# ListView Adapter - ItemID

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have the following ArrayAdapter:

```
public class CriteriosAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Criterio> {

private Context context;

public CriteriosAdapter(Context context, List<Criterio> objects) {
    super(context, 0, objects);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Criterio criterio = getItem(position);
    final CriterioViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_row, parent, false);

        viewHolder = new CriterioViewHolder();
        viewHolder.txtCriterio = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCriterio);
        viewHolder.tgIrregular = (ToggleButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tgIrregular);
        viewHolder.btnCam = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnCam);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else {
        viewHolder = (CriterioViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.txtCriterio.setText(criterio.nome);
    viewHolder.txtCriterio.setTextColor(context.getColor(R.color.white));
    viewHolder.tgIrregular.setChecked(false);

    viewHolder.tgIrregular.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (viewHolder.tgIrregular.isChecked()) {
                viewHolder.btnCam.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                viewHolder.btnCam.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

    viewHolder.btnCam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            FragmentActivity activity = (FragmentActivity)(context);
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
            FotosFragment alertDialog = new FotosFragment();
            alertDialog.show(fm, "fragment_alert");
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

class CriterioViewHolder {

    TextView txtCriterio;
    ToggleButton tgIrregular;

    ImageView btnCam;

}

}
```

Therefore, I want to set the itemID of each item as the ID stored in the database. Because, when the toggle button is setted to ON, I wish to get that value.

Could someone help on it?

Comment: I don't know if I well understood your problem, but you can set a tag to your ToggleButton for example with the item id so that you will be able to retreive it later.

Comment: what `itemID` are you referring to? if an ID is taken from the sqlite db why dont you use a `SimpleCursorAdapter` then?

Comment: Use itemID field in your object Criterio and while fetching data store id in that field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class CriteriosAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Criterio> {

private Context context;

public CriteriosAdapter(Context context, List<Criterio> objects) {
    super(context, 0, objects);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Criterio criterio = getItem(position);
    final CriterioViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_row, parent, false);

        viewHolder = new CriterioViewHolder();
        viewHolder.txtCriterio = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCriterio);
        viewHolder.tgIrregular = (ToggleButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tgIrregular);
        viewHolder.btnCam = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnCam);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else {
        viewHolder = (CriterioViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.txtCriterio.setText(criterio.nome);
    viewHolder.txtCriterio.setTextColor(context.getColor(R.color.white));
    viewHolder.tgIrregular.setChecked(false);

    viewHolder.tgIrregular.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (viewHolder.tgIrregular.isChecked()) {
                viewHolder.btnCam.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                viewHolder.btnCam.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

    viewHolder.btnCam.setOnClickListener(new Listener(position,criterio));

    return convertView;
}

class CriterioViewHolder {

    TextView txtCriterio;
    ToggleButton tgIrregular;

    ImageView btnCam;

}


    class Listener implements OnClickListener {
        private int position;
        Criterio data;

        Listener(int position,Criterio data) {
            this.position = position;

            this.data = data;
        }

        @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // you get the unique id of every item and perform your desired operation
        id = data.getId();


        }
    }

    }
```